# How to allow string to contain ' in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have function that is going to display message containing product name. But problem appeared when Item contained **'** inside. Can this be prevented to take whole string as it is and ignore **'** character

**Calling function**

```
cart.add('<?php echo($imeProizvoda); ?>')
```

NOT WORKING FOR -> Razer Blade 15'

**javascript**

```
var cart = {
        'add': function(product_id) {
            addProductNotice('Proizvod dodat u korpu', '<h3>'+product_id+' dodat u <a href="cart.php">korpu</a>!</h3>', 'success');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use quotes `""` `(:`

Comment: @Ele Not working I tried that already

Comment: json_encode? painless and flexible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a template literal instead of `'` delimiters, allowing you to use both `'` and `"` (relatively common characters), but you would have to escape backticks (which are relatively uncommon):

```
cart.add(`<?php echo($imeProizvoda); ?>`)
```

If you want to be able to use backticks as well, you can replace all backticks in your PHP variable with a backslash plus that backtick:

```
<?php echo(str_replace('`', '\\`', $imeProizvoda)); ?>
```

Comment: I gave an upvote but wondering how to contain all `\``, `'` and `"` in a string?

Comment: Thanks. Is there solution for backticks(just asking)

Comment: @Chaska You can use `str_replace` to replace backticks with escaped versions

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem before, and solved it using json_encode() on the PHP response, like this:

```
cart.add(<?php echo json_encode($imeProizvoda);?>)
```

Comment: What does `json_encode` do exactly in this example and is there more usages of it

Comment: Returns a strnig with the JSON representation of the argument: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php). The method will scape characters like **'** automatically.

Comment: The only protection not covered by this answer is if the name of a protect contains `</script>`, but its hard to counter for that, otherwise I think this is the best answer